# Is dell p2314H better color space than dell U2518D?

Tags: color, monitors

I have 2 monitors (p2314H and u2518D), both not calibrated yet.
when I plug to my mac-book, it automatic create 2 profile for 2 monitor
and when I open these profile detail it show me a little different.
[image]

[image]

Look like p2314H is more space at RED side,
my questtion is why macbook can create 2 different profile without calibrate,
and why ultrasharp monitor is less color than p series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Look like p2314H is more space at RED side, my question is why macbook can create 2 different profile without calibrate

The profiles your Macbook is providing for each monitor without any calibration are based on theoretical monitors made exactly to the manufacturer's specifications for each monitor model without taking the manufacturing tolerances that affect any specific example of each model, not to mention the changes that occurs as each monitor ages, into consideration.

The profiles used by the Mac are most likely based on manufacturer supplied technical information regarding the target performance of each particular monitor model. When you do an actual calibration and profile, you are measuring the actual performance of that specific monitor at that specific time.